# running SharePoint utility on non-SharePoint server

Tags: development, client-object-model, file-upload, assembly-references

I wrote a utility in C# to copy files from a network directory to a SharePoint document library. When the sys admin tries to run the .exe from a non-SharePoint server, he gets the following error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client, Vers
>   ion=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the f
>   ile specified.
>   File name: 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'
>      at SpFileUpload.Program.Main()
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
>   To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.

Is there a way to include the assembly in my .exe so that it will run properly?

Edit: I'm using the SharePoint 2010 [Client Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798388.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instructions on how to deploy the SharePoint 2010 Client Object Model assemblies can be found in [Client Object Model Distribution and Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee539757%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

> Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 installs
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll and
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll in %ProgramFiles%\Common
>   Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\ISAPI for easy access
>   in development. You must have both Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll and
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll to develop a solution remotely
>   with the .NET managed object model. For a Windows Forms, Windows
>   Presentation Foundation (WPF), or other application that calls the
>   .NET managed SharePoint Foundation client APIs, to function, the
>   client computer must have the SharePoint Foundation client DLLs
>   installed. The client DLLs must be distributed with the application by
>   using Microsoft's [SharePoint Foundation 2010 Client Object Model
>   Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=b4579045-b183-4ed4-bf61-dc2f0deabe47).

Comment: Does that mean that the server admin has to install the Client Object Model redistributable on the server?

Comment: Yes. Running the install will deploy the .NET assemblies that implement the SharePoint 2010 Client Object Model (specifically Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll and Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll)

Comment: If you are adding these DLLs using NuGet packages in your project/Application, there is no need for the System Admin to install a redistributable in his server. These DLLs will be included in your project/application as a package wherever you deploy the application, application will work fine. I think that is the beauty of NuGet packages. Don't you agree Rob? Why you need to depend on the System Admin to get your stuff working?

Comment: Make sure Copy Local is set to true if you inspect the properties of your Sharepoint dll's.

Answer (score 2):

Please Use NuGet Package Manager to add DLLs to your project[image]